# Disable wireless Android(ADB) debugging without root

Tags: android, debugging, adb, remote-debugging

is there a way to disable wireless debugging with ADB without root?

Currently I'm using `adb tcpip <port>` to enable it, but only way to disable it is to use the root command, or restart the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable, run the command `adb usb`

> adb usb : Restart the adb server listening on USB.

This is listed on the official [android site](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)